# How does a Service communicate with its Activity? How can a Service call a method in the Activity, which started that Service?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

Suppose I have an Activity that's a list. It calls a Service when this Activity starts.  The Service will do background stuff--download, parse, and fill the list.

My question is this: How can the **Service communicate with the Activity**?
How can I call a method in the Activity, from the Service? (I'm new to OOP)

The Service is started like this:

```
hello_service = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(hello_service);
```

One of the things my service does is download and parse an XML. After that, it needs to fill a list! So, I want to pass the parsed stuff back to the Activity, and call a method in the Activity to fill that list.

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked a very similar question, [best way for service that starts activity to communicate with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274641/best-way-for-service-that-starts-activity-to-communicate-with-it/), that got a very helpful answer.

Also, consider using `AsyncTask` instead of a service if the service doesn't need to be alive when the activity is closed. Then you don't need to bother with the server/activity-communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can set activity object to service and invoke methods of your activity from service. But you must to care about thread-safe when you update your UI.

Hope this helps! [Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356)

Comment: What does "set activity object to service" mean?

Comment: In service you create static method smth like this:
public static void setMainActivity(YourActivityType activity) {
  YOUR_ACTIVITY = activity;
}

and then, before invoke startService() method just call YourService.setMainActivity(this) from your activity.

Comment: Thanks. It maeks sense. But what about thread-safe? Why would this not be safe?

Comment: UI and service run in separate threads. If you want to change UI from service thread you must to take care bout thread safety.

Comment: I like this method as it is much simpler than the complication solutions using intents.  But, is it safe?  Is there any chance that the reference you pass to the service might somehow become invalid, resulting in an exception when you try to use it later?  Can the Activity object be discarded without the corresponding Service object also being discarded too?  Since they are running in the same process I am thinking no, but I need to be sure.