# Communicate with a started service

Tags: android

I'm trying to periodically capture image from camera using a service. To keep the service alive when the activity is paused/stop, I should start it as a started service - that's what I learned studying Service documentations (I'm a newbie trying to learn Android)

How do I communicate with the service? Say, I want to send some notifications to the activity (which started the service) when I've captured some photo from the service?

PS. I checked the answer [How does a Service communicate with its Activity? How can a Service call a method in the Activity, which started that Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280845/how-does-a-service-communicate-with-its-activity-how-can-a-service-call-a-metho) here but that's not that helpful.

Comment: have you solved you problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample code.

http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html